# ng-grid filtering always filters all rows

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

At one point, this was working, but it seems to have stopped, and I'm scratching my head as to why. I'm using Angular 1.2.8, with ng-grid 2.0.7. I'm defining my grid options like so:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'ExternalCustomerId', displayName: 'Customer Id' },
        { field: 'CustomerName', displayName: 'Customer Name' },
        { field: 'ExternalUserId', displayName: 'Customer User Id' },
        { field: 'CustomerUserName', displayName: 'Customer User Name' },
        { field: 'EventName', displayName: 'Event' },
        { field: 'CreatedOn', displayName: 'Date', cellFilter: "date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'" }
    ],
    plugins: [
        new ngGridCsvExportPlugin(),
        new ngGridWYSIWYGPlugin()
    ],
    data: 'customerUserEvents',
    enableColumnResize: true,
    enableRowSelection: false,
    enableCellSelection: true,
    showFooter: true,
    showFilter: true,
    filterOptions: { filterText: '', useExternalFilter: false }
};
```

And the data is showing up correctly:

[image: ng-grid showing correctly]

However, as soon as I enter any value in the "filter" field, the entire grid goes blank:

[image: blank ng-grid]

No errors are reported in the console log or anywhere else so far as I can see. Happens across multiple browsers. The same thing happens if I bind a regular textbox to the `$scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText`, or if I specify an initial value for `$scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you just make a filter option and set grid options filter option to that. IE. 
 $scope.filterOptions = {
        filterText: ''
      };
filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions

Comment: @crackhaus - Great question. Turns out it goes blank, just like implementing a filter via the other means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it must have been a bug of some sort in ng-grid 2.0.7, as when I upgraded to the (not-yet-released) 2.0.8 (https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/tree/2.0.8), the problem went away. Still not sure precisely what it was, but on to the next story at this point...